# Using assignment statements after static declaration

Tags: c

The following program gives an output of `1 1` instead of `1 2` which is the output when I use `static int count = 0` instead of the separate initialisation `count = 0`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun()
{
  static int count;
  count = 0;
  count++;
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%d ", fun());
  printf("%d ", fun());
  return 0;
}
```

Does this mean that a separate initialisation overrides the static declaration which is supposed to preserve values between calls?

I searched quite extensively but couldn't find any answer explicitly confirming my belief.

Comment: That "separate initialisation" *isn't*; it's an assignment.

Comment: `count = 0;` is just a simple assignment. There is nothing that separates it from any other assignment you would do to `count`. How do you think the compiler differentiate it and treat it as an initialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count = 0;` is an explicit assignment of 0 to `count`, which happens *every* time the function is called.

Hence your output.

Writing `static int count;` will *initialise* `count` to 0 due to it having static storage duration. Is that what you wanted?

Finally, `fun` is not thread safe due to a non-atomic type being used and incremented without mutual exclusion units.

Comment: Oh! So that means even if we use static, it does not mean that the value is retained between function calls if other assignment statements are used?

Comment: @momo: Assignment changes the value, and that value is retained between function calls.

Comment: @momo Even if the value is retained between calls, it is reassigned to `0` with `count = 0;`. Can you please read a manual/book instead of speculating?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun()
{
  static int count;
  count = 0;         // for static variables this is not a initialisation
  count++;
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%d ", fun());
  printf("%d ", fun());
  return 0;
}
```

`count = 0` means assignment not initialisation

each time you call `fun()`,  `count` will be assignment by `0`

if you want get right output use [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/) code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fun()
{
  static int count = 0;
  count++;
  return count;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%d ", fun());
  printf("%d ", fun());
  return 0;
}
```